# Really large dogs in Scotland; Which breed are they?

Tags: dogs, identification

In Edinburgh many people seem to have these massive dogs, they look as big as a fully grown lion (at least to my 4 year old son).

This picture does not do justice to how big this dog was but it really was a large dog. There were others too which were in darker colors but equally big.

Which dog breed is this and is it local to Scotland? Would you please kindly add some links so i can study about them before trying to import one?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a Saint Bernhard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but this looks like a St. Bernhard breed of dog.

Wikipedia describes them as:

> The St. Bernard or St Bernard (UK: /ˈbɜːrnərd/, US: /bərˈnɑːrd/) is a breed of very large working dog from the western Alps. They were originally bred for rescue at the Great St Bernard Pass on the Italian-Swiss border, and Little St Bernard Pass in the Italian-French border,[2] located close to one another. The two hospices were built and run by the same monk brotherhood. The breed has become famous through tales of alpine rescues, as well as for its enormous size.

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Bernard_(dog))

The pictures seem to fit the bill quite well:

[image]